# Why itertools.product dosen't return key and value from a dictionary in sequence? Help pls

Tags: python, loops, nested, product, python-itertools

I have a situation that is as follows.
A nested loop like this:

```
d = [{'val1': 1, 'val2':2}, {'val3': 3, 'val4':4}, {'val5': 5, 'val6':6}, {'val7': 7, 'val8':8}, {'val9': 9, 'val10':10}]

num = list(range(len(d))
new_list = []
for i in num:
  for k, v in d[i].items():
    new_list.append([k ,v])
```

The result will be this:

```
[['val1', 1],
 ['val2', 2],
 ['val3', 3],
 ['val4', 4],
 ['val5', 5],
 ['val6', 6],
 ['val7', 7],
 ['val8', 8],
 ['val9', 9],
 ['val10', 10]]
```

Bu need to find a way to summarize these loops, either using functions like Map and Filter, or with the Itertools.product I read that turns nested loops into a loop only. So I made this code:

```
new_list = []
for i, (k,v) in itertools.product(num, d[i].items()):
    new_list.append([k ,v])
```

And the result is this:

```
    [['val9', 9],
 ['val10', 10],
 ['val9', 9],
 ['val10', 10],
 ['val9', 9],
 ['val10', 10],
 ['val9', 9],
 ['val10', 10],
 ['val9', 9],
 ['val10', 10]]
```

So I wanted to know if there is any way for `itertools.product` to produce the same result as the code with nested loops, that is, the outputs are in sequence and not just repeating the last two values.
If there is a solution with `map` or `filter`, it is also welcome.

### Update

@BrokenBenchmark
My problem is a little more complex, so can you helpe me?
The problem is this:

```
d = [{'val1': 1, 'val2':2}, {'val3': 3, 'val4':4}, {'val5': 5, 'val6':6}, {'val7': 7, 'val8':8}, {'val9': 9, 'val10':10}]  
d2 = [{'val1': 1, 'val2':2}, {'val3': 3, 'val4':4}, {'val5': 5, 'val6':6}, {'val7': 7, 'val8':8}, {'val9': 9, 'val10':10}]  
num = list(range(len(d))
new_list = []  
for i in num:      
    for k_i, v_i in d[i].items():
          for j in num:              
              for k_j, v_j in d2[j].items():                  
                  new_list.append([k_i, k_j])
```

Do you have a solution for that? That can replace this nested loop for something that speed up the code.

The output that I need is lists with key from dict 1 along with all keys from dict 2 (I need to compare each key from dict 1 with each key from dict 2). The output should be this:

```
[['Key1_dict1', 'Key1_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key2_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key3_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key4_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key5_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key6_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key7_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key8_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key9_dict2'],
['Key1_dict1', 'Key10_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key1_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key2_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key3_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key4_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key5_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key6_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key7_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key8_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key9_dict2'],
['Key2_dict1', 'Key10_dict2']]
```

And so on.

Comment: Suggested corrections to question: in code blocks 1 and 2, change `num` initialization to `num = list(range(len(d))`; in code block 2, also change the `append()` line to `new_list.append([k_i, k_j])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution #1:

```
        d = [{'val1': 1, 'val2':2}, {'val3': 3, 'val4':4}, {'val5': 5, 'val6':6}, {'val7': 7, 'val8':8}, {'val9': 9, 'val10':10}]  
        d2 = [{'val1': 1, 'val2':2}, {'val3': 3, 'val4':4}, {'val5': 5, 'val6':6}, {'val7': 7, 'val8':8}, {'val9': 9, 'val10':10}]

        new_list = [[k_i, k_j] for i in range(len(d)) for k_i, v_i in d[i].items() for j in range(len(d2)) for k_j, v_j in d2[j].items()]
```

Output:

```
[['val1', 'val1'], ['val1', 'val2'], ['val1', 'val3'], ['val1', 'val4'], ['val1', 'val5'], ['val1', 'val6'], ['val1', 'val7'], ['val1', 'val8'], ['val1', 'val9'], ['val1', 'val10'], ['val2', 'val1'], ['val2', 'val2'], ['val2', 'val3'], ['val2', 'val4'], ['val2', 'val5'], ['val2', 'val6'], ['val2', 'val7'], ['val2', 'val8'], ['val2', 'val9'], ['val2', 'val10'], ['val3', 'val1'], ['val3', 'val2'], ['val3', 'val3'], ['val3', 'val4'], ['val3', 'val5'], ['val3', 'val6'], ['val3', 'val7'], ['val3', 'val8'], ['val3', 'val9'], ['val3', 'val10'], ['val4', 'val1'], ['val4', 'val2'], ['val4', 'val3'], ['val4', 'val4'], ['val4', 'val5'], ['val4', 'val6'], ['val4', 'val7'], ['val4', 'val8'], ['val4', 'val9'], ['val4', 'val10'], ['val5', 'val1'], ['val5', 'val2'], ['val5', 'val3'], ['val5', 'val4'], ['val5', 'val5'], ['val5', 'val6'], ['val5', 'val7'], ['val5', 'val8'], ['val5', 'val9'], ['val5', 'val10'], ['val6', 'val1'], ['val6', 'val2'], ['val6', 'val3'], ['val6', 'val4'], ['val6', 'val5'], ['va...
```

Solution # 2:

```
        k, k2 = chain(*[m.keys() for m in d]), chain(*[m.keys() for m in d2])
        new_list_of_tuples = list(product(k, k2)) # if tuples are OK as key pairs
        new_list = [[*x] for x in product(k, k2)] # if you need lists as key pairs
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a nested `for` loop, you can use `.extend()` to append the key-value pairs of a dictionary to a list, and use `map()` to transform each element in `.items()` to a list.

`itertools.product()` can reduce nesting in `for` loops, when, for example, you need to loop over each pair of elements in two lists. It is *not* a silver bullet for removing all nested `for` loops.

```py
data = [{'val1': 1, 'val2':2}, {'val3': 3, 'val4':4}, {'val5': 5, 'val6':6}, {'val7': 7, 'val8':8}, {'val9': 9, 'val10':10}]

result = []
for dictionary in data:
    result.extend(map(list, dictionary.items()))    

print(result)
```